# Tkinter Not Updating Label Text

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a program written in Python that on click of a button it will roll 3 dice and update the GUI with the rolls.

Here is the code:

```
import random
import Tkinter

class Die():
    def roll(self):
        value = random.randint(1,6)
        self.display.config(text=value)

    def __init__(self, display):
        self.value = 0
        self.display = Tkinter.Label(display, text=self.value, relief='ridge', borderwidth=5, bg='white')
        self.display.pack(side='left')

class DiceRoller:
    def rollDice(self):
        Die.roll

    def __init__(self):
        window = Tkinter.Tk()
        window.title("Die Roller")
        frame = Tkinter.Frame(window)
        self.dice = [Die(frame), Die(frame), Die(frame)]
        rollAgain = Tkinter.Button(window, text = "Roll Again", command=self.rollDice)
        frame.pack()
        rollAgain.pack(side='bottom')
        window.mainloop()

program = DiceRoller()
```

Everything about the code works except for the fact that the function `rollDice()` is not updating the dice labels on the frame. I click my `rollAgain` button yet the text does not update.

Can anybody help me out? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my issue by doing the below:

```
def rollDice(self):
    for die in self.dice:
        die.roll()
```

By looping through my dices I can roll each one. This avoids having to create a new Die object, which would obviously create 4 dices and I only want 3.

So for anyone who stumbles upon this, there's the solution.